# How to convert this Java lambda code to Groovy equivalent

Tags: groovy

I have a method which works but need to convert it to use Groovy as the code base is all groovy. I also believe this can be done more succinctly using Groovy but I'm better at using lambdas so I tried that first but I am struggling to achieve the same with Groovy. I'd really be grateful if someone could help with this.

Here is the code:

```
 public ArrayList<GameCredits> getCreditsList(CreditGained 
                                           creditsAccumulated, 
     Players playerList) {
    List<GameCredits> credits = creditsAccumulated.credits
    List<GameCredit> newCredits = []
    boolean playerMatched
    //Match Players to their credits and create new credits for unmatched
    playerList.players.stream()
            .filter { Player player -> player.playerKey != null }
            .each { Player player ->
                 playerMatched = false
                 credits.stream()
                .filter { GameCredit credit -> (credit?.creditIdentifier && 

                      credit?.creditIdentifier.equals(player.playerKey)) }

            .each { GameCredit credit ->
               credit.rank = player.rank
               credit.playerEmail = player.emailAddress
               credit.firstName = player.firstName
               credit.lastName = player.lastName
               playerMatched = true
        }
        if(!playerMatched){
              GameCredit credit=new GameCredit()
              credit.rank = player.rank
              credit.playerEmail = player.emailAddress
              credit.firstName = player.firstName
              credit.lastName = player.lastName
              newcredits.push(newGameCredits)
        }
    }
    credits.addAll(newCredits)
    credits
}
```

Here's what I attempted but I know there would be a better way.

```
public ArrayList<GameCredits> getCreditsList(CreditGained creditsAccumulated, 
     Players playerList) {
    List<GameCredits> credits = creditsAccumulated.credits
    List<GameCredit> newCredits = []
    boolean playerMatched
    //Match Players to their credits and create new credits for unmatched
    playerList.players.findAll
             { Player player -> player.playerKey != null }
            .each { Player player ->
                 playerMatched = false
                 credits
                .findAll { GameCredit credit -> (credit?.creditIdentifier && 
                 credit?.creditIdentifier.equals(player.playerKey)) }

            .each { GameCredit credit ->
               credit.rank = player.rank
               credit.playerEmail = player.emailAddress
               credit.firstName = player.firstName
               credit.lastName = player.lastName
               playerMatched = true
        }
        if(!playerMatched){
              GameCredit newGameCredits=new GameCredit()
              newGameCredits.rank = player.rank
              newGameCredits.playerEmail = player.emailAddress
              newGameCredits.firstName = player.firstName
              newGameCredits.lastName = player.lastName
              newcredits.push(newGameCredits)
        }
    }
    credits.addAll(newCredits)
    credits
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does that code mutate the `creditsAccumulated.credits` elements as a side effect?  What have you tried? Where didn't it work?

Comment: The game credits are stored in creditaAccumulated. What I have currently shown here already works but is using Java 8 lambdas and I want to convert to Groovy

Comment: there are a lot of answers @ stackoverflow to this question. just type in search `groovy lambda`

Comment: Are there multiple threads in your app?  Any other thread looking at `creditsAccumulated` will get unpredictable results :-(

Comment: No there are no multiple threads.  I haven't found an answer which is able to process the data meeting the multiple conditions in any decent way.  Like I said, what I have solves the problem, I am just looking for improvements to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on it (I removed the side-effect on CreditGained):

```
List<GameCredits> collectCredits(CreditGained credits, Players players) {
  credits.credits + players.players.collectMany { Player player ->
    if (!player.playerKey) {
      Collections.emptyList() // quick exit for player without key
    } else {
      List<GameCredit> matches = player.credits.findAll {
        it?.creditIdentifier == player.playerKey
      }

      if (matches) {
        // return credit(s) matched to player (with updated metadata)
        matches.each { GameCredit credit ->
          credit.with {
            rank = player.rank
            lastName = player.lastName
            firstName = player.firstName
            playerEmail = player.emailAddress
          }
        }
      } else {
        // return 1 new credit for player
        new GameCredit(
          rank: player.rank,
          lastName: player.lastName,
          firstName: player.firstName,
          playerEmail: player.emailAddress,
          creditIdentifier: player.playerKey // guessing you want this too...
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It seems that Groovy doesn't offer much more than Java lambda in this situation.